# Show/Hide text JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, show-hide

This example show/hide text http://codepen.io/svinkle/pen/AqwDu is something I intend to adapt in my website , but how to fix the code so that does not repeat the first lines of paragraph?
In the example the text begins with "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum facilisnim wanted molestie", which has just been repeated before 3 points ( ... ) How to fix it?

```
// Select all text areas
var textArea = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js=content]'),    
maxText = 100;

// For each one...
[].forEach.call( textArea, function( el ) {

var textAreaLength = el.innerHTML.length,
teaserText = el.innerHTML.substr(0, 100),
fullText = el.innerHTML,
showTeaser = false;    

// Check to see if this text length is more
// than the max
if (textAreaLength >= maxText) {
// Set flag
showTeaser = true;

// Set teaser text  
el.innerHTML = teaserText;
el.innerHTML += el.innerHTML + '...';

// Create button
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'Show More';
button.classList.add('button');
el.appendChild(button);

// Button click event
button.onclick = function () {
  if (showTeaser === true) {
    // Update flag
    showTeaser = false;

    // Update button text
    this.innerHTML = 'Show Less';

    // Show full text
    el.innerHTML = fullText;

    // Re-append the button
    el.appendChild(this);
  } else {
    // Update flag
    showTeaser = true;

    // Update button text
    this.innerHTML = 'Show More';

    // Show teaser text
    el.innerHTML = teaserText;
    el.innerHTML += el.innerHTML + '...';

    // Re-append the button
    el.appendChild(this);
  }
  return false;
};
} else { 
// Show full text
el.innerHTML = fullText;
}   

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
el.innerHTML += el.innerHTML + '...';
```

The error is in above line.You're adding the `el.innerHTML` twice. At first you are adding it with `...` and then adding it with itself because of shorthand `+=` operator.

It should be just

```
el.innerHTML += '...';
```

It's present in multiple places, you may need to edit all those.